# Persist same dependency in different transactions issue

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hibernate, jpa

I have a part of program where implemented synchronization in parallel way with another system. The each synchronization process opens new transaction. Synchronized objects going to map on some data and to persist.
The data on which objects are going to be mapped can be persisted before and can be persisted in synchronization time.

My persistent layer provides cascade operation, so I do not care to persist about all dependencies.

### Issue

In mapped object was not persisted before and in synchronization time it is going to be save in different threads at same time appears hibernate exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [my.project.entity.CrmCaseLink#27];
nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [my.project.entity.CrmCaseLink#27]
```

### My tries to solve issue did not help

**1.**

I tried to use cache where from I can get same `CrmCaseLink` for different threads but it does not solved my issue.

**2.**

Another time I tried

```
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = Constants.CRM_CASE_LINK_CACHE, cacheManager = Constants.GUAVA_CACHE_MANAGER)
@Service
public class CrmCaseLinkService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(CrmCaseLinkService.class);
    @Autowired
    private CrmCaseLinkRepository crmCaseLinkRepository;

    @Cacheable(key = "#id")
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public synchronized CrmCaseLink findOne(Long id) {
        LOGGER.debug("trace loading crm case link by specified id: {}", id);
        return Optional.ofNullable(crmCaseLinkRepository.findOne(id))
                .orElseGet(() -> crmCaseLinkRepository.save(new CrmCaseLink(id)));
    }
}
```

### Question

Why cache is mistake here? I expected `hiberate` able to manage same non persisted entity in different transactions. I was sure that cache solution with new transaction in separate spring bean is indisputable solution, but it also doesn't help me.

### Additional details

java8, spring, spring data jpa, postgres, hibernate5, jetty container

Answer (score 1):

### The issues reason explanation

I think the issue appears because of in provided solution detached entity objects are used. As you see I create new transaction for synchronized singleton method

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public synchronized CrmCaseLink findOne(Long id) {
    LOGGER.debug("trace loading crm case link by specified id: {}", id);
    return Optional.ofNullable(crmCaseLinkRepository.findOne(id))
            .orElseGet(() -> crmCaseLinkRepository.save(new CrmCaseLink(id)));
}
```

to persist new object if one is absent in DB storage. But `public synchronized CrmCaseLink findOne` is used from another transaction to get the `CrmCaseLink` and to map it on other object. To map and persist other entity successfully I have to use attached `CrmCaseLink`.

### Solution code example

I've changed code in next way:

1. DB lookup and persist are different methods
2. Persist method must be synchronized and processed in new tranzaction
3. Remove caching because mapping needs attached entities, and different transactions use this service to load `CrmCaseLink`.

Code example:

```
@Service
public class CrmCaseLinkManager implements CrmLinkManager {
    @Autowired
    private CrmCaseLinkRepository crmCaseLinkRepository;

    @Override
    public CrmCaseLink findOne(Long id) {
        return crmCaseLinkRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public synchronized void save(Long id) {
        if (crmCaseLinkRepository.exists(id)) {
            return;
        }
        crmCaseLinkRepository.save(new CrmCaseLink(id));
    }
}
```

code part where from it is used demonstrates how to get necessary attached entity from implemented service:

```
T getOrCreateCrmLink(Long id, CrmLinkManager<T> crmLinkManager) {
    T crmLink = crmLinkManager.findOne(id);
    if (crmLink == null) {
        crmLinkManager.save(id);
        crmLink = crmLinkManager.findOne(id);
    }
    return crmLink;
}
```